# Django - Getting latest of each choice

Tags: django, postgresql

I have two models: the gas station and the price of a product. The price can up to have 4 choices, one for each product type, not every station has all four products. I want to query the latest entry of each of those products, preferably in a single query:

```
   class GasStation(models.Model):
        place_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    class Price(models.Model):

        class Producto(models.TextChoices):
            GASOLINA_REGULAR = 'GR', _('Gasolina regular')
            GASOINA_PREMIUM = 'GP', _('Gasolina premium')
            DIESEL_REGULAR = 'DR', _('Diesel regular')
            DIESEL_PREMIUM = 'DP', _('Diesel premium')

        product = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Producto.choices)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
        estacion = models.ForeignKey(GasStation,
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                             null=True,
                             related_name='prices')
```

I've tried with:

```
station.price.filter(product__in=['GR', 'GP', 'DR', 'DP']).latest()
```

But it only returns the latest of the whole queryset, not the latest price of each product type. I want to avoid querying for each individual product because some stations don't sell all types .Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for annotations and [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions). Below is what I think might work. Your models aren't fully defined. If you need the whole Price instance, then this won't work for you. Subquery can only annotate a single field.

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
stations = GasStation.objects.annotate(
    latest_regular=Subquery(
        Price.objects.filter(station_id=OuterRef("pk"), product="GR").order_by('-updated').values("price")[:1]
    ),
    latest_premium=Subquery(
        Price.objects.filter(station_id=OuterRef("pk"), product="GP").order_by('-updated').values("price")[:1]
    ),
    ...
)

station = stations.get(something_here)
station.latest_premium, station.latest_regular
```

You can make this more concise by using a dict comprehension iterating over your Product short codes and then doing `.annotate(**annotations)`

Comment: What do you mean by: "my models are not fully defined?"

Comment: The models are missing the relationship fields so I had to guess at the related name and the `Price` model doesn't include a field indicating the actual value.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to copy and paste the foreign key field and price on Price model. I'll edit. Thank you very much.